# Error instalando MySQL

Tags: mysql

hola compre una miniPc con windows 11 al instalar mysql me da un error en la instalación no se si me falta una configuración de algo abjunto mensaje

```
Attempting to start service MySQL80...
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 7388
InnoDB initialization has started.
Unable to create temporary file inside "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp"; errno: 13
Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
Data Dictionary initialization failed.
Aborting
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  MySQL Community Server - GPL..................
MySQL failed to start because of the following error(s):
Unable to create temporary file inside "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp"; errno: 13
Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
Data Dictionary initialization failed.
Aborting

Una tarea solo se puede desechar si tiene un estado de finalización (RanToCompletion, Faulted o Canceled).
Ended configuration step: Starting the server
```

Answer (score 1):

Dice en el log

```
Unable to create temporary file inside "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp"; errno: 13
```

Pareciera que Windows no es muy feliz dejando crear el directorio que mysql usa allí adentro. Ejecuta tu instalador con permisos de Administrador.

Comment: hola gracias ya di todos los permisos de administrador y sige el error

Comment: @marlonmoreno No des permisos. Clic derecho en el instalador, ejecutar como Administrador. Hay carpetas que windows no quiere que modifiquen otros procesos.